# É possível criar aplicativos para Android usando HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, android, css

Queria muito começar a desenvolver aplicativos para celulares Android, porém tenho um conhecimento quase nulo sobre o SDK do sistema operacional, tenho mais conhecimento sobre HTML, Javascript, CSS.

Eu tenho em mente que criar um app Android deva ser **bem** diferente da constituição de um web site em html, mas talvez deva existir algum jeito emular um arquivo HTML como se fosse um app ou algum outra forma.

Queria saber se existe algum plugin para isso ao algo que deixe pelo menos mais 'fácil' e amigável escrever os códigos para aplicação.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no http://www.appgyver.com/ - uma variante híbrida do PhoneGap.

Comment: Cara, se você quer criar apps estáveis e robustos, trabalha com o SDK.
O nativo é **sempre** melhor. http://www.businessinsider.com/the-mobile-web-is-dead-its-all-about-apps-2014-4?fb_action_ids=10152705418059746&fb_action_types=og.recommends&utm_content=bufferee5dc&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Comment: Aconselho fortemente você investir um tempo em conhecer o SDK Android. Excelente plataforma de desenvolvimento. Se desejar mais detalhes pode me contatar: aspnetwf@gmail.com

Comment: Eu já tentei várias vezes, mas não consigo de jeito nenhum entender a lógica do java e dos códigos do Android. Também tenho dificuldade na hora de assinar os apks =(

Comment: React Native é uma boa opção.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Existem alguns Frameworks que usam exatamente o que você procura: **HTML5, CSS3 e JavaScript**.

- [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)
- [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/)
- [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)
- [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

O banco de dados é o [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/), usado pelo local storage do HTML5. Com esses Frameworks você consegue gerar Apps para *Android*, *IPhone*, *Windows Phone* e *Blackberry*, tudo com o mesmo código.

Comment: Eu já tinha ouvido falar sobre o phonegap, não achava que era para isso '-'. Como ele funciona? Seria criar um arquivo html normal, ou ele só oferece uma api que é parecida com o html?

Comment: Na verdade ele usa um WebView como "gatilho" para um arquivo .html por exemplo. Dai a navegação é igual a de um site. Você faz a programação usando HTML5, CSS3 e JavaScript igual a um site notmal.

Comment: Mas por acaso você sabe se trava, da algum problema que uma aplicação Android não daria...?

Comment: Eu ia começar a usar o Parse (https://parse.com/) como banco de dados. Vocês acham ele bom?

Comment: Depende do que você esta querendo implementar. Logicamente o app nativo em alguns casos tem uma performance melhor do que o app gerado com algum framework. Mas, em muitos casos, eles atendem bem as necessidades mais comuns. Tais frameworks são utilizados por diversos aplicativos conhecidos e por grandes empresas. Pode usar sem medo.

Comment: ok kkk eu nem sei instalar os programas para começar '-'

Comment: Hugo, por exemplo: se alguém cria-se só o começo do app, tipo instalar o Phonegap e tudo mais, e essa pessoa me passa-se esses arquivos para eu continuar o desenvolvimento do html, javascript, teria algum problema ou é melhor eu começar sozinho?
Pq eu acho que no eclipse já sai o arquivo no formato apk que é semelhante ao zip ae daria para eu ir editando. Ou não é bem assim?

Comment: ok, achei que teria algum problema e tals. Mas da pra criar o arquivo apk dentro do eclipse ou só no Google Play?

Comment: Iago, não tem problema em fazer isso. Normalmente nas empresas o desenvolvimento é colaborativo. Eu por exemplo uso o Github para isso. Mas de qualquer forma é interessante que você aprenda a levantar o ambiente em sua máquina para evitar de ficar de um lado para o outro com os arquivos que você mesmo poderia estar alterando e testando. Isso economiza bastante tempo. Segue uns tutoriais que vão te ajudar nesse ponto:   http://www.loiane.com/2012/06/comecando-com-phone-gap-cordova-hello-world-android  e   http://www.mobiltec.com.br/blog/index.php/tutorial-de-phonegap-primeiros-passos

Comment: **Obrigado n__n =D**

Comment: Desisto! Isso não é pra mim :p _é muito complicado_